# How to restore dump file on android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I've inserted a lot of data into my android application. Now I want to bundle this data into my app. I only have a database.db file now, how can I restore it to fresh installed app's database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this method:

```
 private void importDatabaseFromAssets() {
    try {
        InputStream myInput = getAssets().open("your_database.db");
        String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + "your_database_name";
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```